# Is there a source selection Directshow Filter available?

Tags: c++, directshow

I am in need of a source selection filter for Directshow but cannot find either a commercial or open source product.

I need the opposite of the Infinite Tee filter - I want something that takes two inputs and has one output and then I can select which input is used via an interface.

I have a chain of effects that I would like to be able to switch on or off at will without altering the graph.  I could use VMR9 if I had to but usually use EVR, so would like a filter of some kind.  The filter would be accepting the same type of input in terms of size and colour space.

Is there anything available or do I need to write something myself?

Comment: Create such a filter by yourself. You don't need any comprehensive processing, so it will be very easy.

Comment: [GMFBridge](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge/) could be used for that, or you can look at it's source.